# I need to convert a tear range to comma separated range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a single column in my worksheet that has year ranges in each cell. (i.e 1995-2005)  I know formulas pretty well, but I do not know VBA.  Could someone tell me a scripts I can use to change this range into a comma separated year range in a single cell.  (i.e 1995,1995,1997, etc)

Comment: Do you have an example of what your data looks like? And the way you want it to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code converts as cell value like '1995-2000' to '1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000'. This will continue for all the cells specified in the Range

```
Sub commaYear()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cellValue As Range
Dim strtYear As Integer
Dim endYear As Integer
Dim tempCelValue As String
Set rng = Range("A1:A10") 'Specify your Coloumn range

For Each cellValue In rng.Cells
    If (cellValue.Value <> "") Then
        strtYear = CInt(Trim(Split(cellValue.Value, "-")(0)))
        endYear = CInt(Trim(Split(cellValue.Value, "-")(1)))
        'tempCelValue = "'"
        While (strtYear <= endYear)
            If (strtYear = endYear) Then
                tempCelValue = tempCelValue & strtYear
                strtYear = strtYear + 1
            Else
                tempCelValue = tempCelValue & strtYear & ","
                strtYear = strtYear + 1
            End If
        Wend
        cellValue.Value = tempCelValue
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That works to create the range, but half the numbers, it changes the "," and makes a huge number.  How do you prevent that?

Comment: I figured it out.  Had to uncomment tempCelValue

Answer (score 0):

For example: http://prntscr.com/9yhns8

```
=CONCATENATE(A1;",";A2;",";A3;",";A4;",";A5;",";A6;",";A7;",";A8;",";A9;",";A10;",";A11)
```